# Redis modo réplica (maestro-esclavos)

Tags: base-de-datos, redis

Estoy utilizando Redis en modo réplica con un nodo maestro y otro nodo esclavo.

¿Es posible convertir de forma automática un esclavo en nodo maestro, cuando el nodo maestro falla?

Sé que manualmente se le indica al nodo maestro con el comando `SLAVEOF NO ONE` que se convierta en un nodo maestro, pero me gustaría saber si se puede cambiar solo cuando se detecte que el nodo maestro principal está fallando o no está disponible.

Comment: Hola Encarna, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en Español. El idioma de esta comunidad es el español, por favor, traduce la pregunta.

Comment: Ya sé la solución a la pregunta.

He empleado Sentinel (pensaba que solo lo podía usar al configurar un clúster).

Saludos.